# Can't use a file from Zend Frame Work

Tags: php, zend-framework, dreamweaver

I want to use a file called Date.php from Zend Framework in one of my php file. When I write the require_once function,

```
<?php require_once("Zend/Date.php") ?>
```

and want to see the php file in live view in Dreamweaver or in browser I get error messages like below

```
Warning: require_once(Zend/Date.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
C:\xampp\htdocs\dream_server\explorers\explorerlist.php on line 2


Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'Zend/Date.php' (include_path='.;C:\phpincludes\ZendFramework\library') in
C:\xampp\htdocs\dream_server\explorers\explorerlist.php on line 2
```

To mention, I have configured the zend Framework with dreamweaver and put the zend framework in

```
C:\phpincludes\ZendFramework
```

and the windows section of my php.ini file was like

```
; Windows: "\path1;\path2"
include_path=".;C:\xampp\php\PEAR"
```

and changed to this

```
; Windows: "\path1;\path2"
include_path=".;C:\phpincludes\ZendFramework\library"
```

now how can I solve This problem.

Comment: Where's the structure of C:\phpincludes\ZendFramework\library? Do you have Zend folder inside?

Comment: zend folder is inside the library folder @M.M.

Answer (score 0):

Disable open_basedir in your php.ini

```
open_basedir =
```

or on your vhost

```
php_admin_value open_basedir none
```